# How to add an offset to trigger a jQuery function sooner?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've added some classes through jquery to a sticky navigation that activates on the class "start". It's working right except for I want it to occur about 100px above where it is currently happening because the nav has a top-padding of 90px on it. I've tried adding in an offset of 100px but can't seem to get it to work, I'm assuming because I have a scrollTop on but I am not sure. Any insight would be very helpful!

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
       var scroll_start = 0;
       var startchange = $('.start');
       var offset = startchange.offset();
       $(document).scroll(function() { 
          scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
          if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color','rgba(255,255,255,0.9)');
              $('.nav-links a').css('color','#404041');
              $('.logo img').attr("src","img/tenure_logo_black.svg");
           } else {
              $('.main-nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
              $('.nav-links a').css('color','#ffffff');
              $('.logo img').attr("src","img/tenure_logo.svg");
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a your HTML/CSS here? or better if you could create a **[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() - 100;
```

OR

```
scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop() + 100;
```

according to your need.